# Generic with method as upper bound cannot take generic type as parameter

Tags: scala, generics

I'm trying to create a generic factory method that has an upper bound of a method that takes a parameter of that generic type and returns something of that generic type. I tried this,

```
def apply[Type <: {def *(that: Type): Type}](length: Int)(implicit manifest: Manifest[Type]) = new Array[Type](length)
```

but I get this error,

```
Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement
```

Is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

According to that error message you should define `*` as generic function like this:
`def apply[Type <: {def *[Type](that: Type): Type}](length: Int)(implicit manifest: Manifest[Type]) = new Array[Type](length)`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. Say I pass an int to the apply function. I want there to be a method * that takes an int and returns an int. I don't want the type to define a generic method *.